# Android values folder to different display sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

Have declared next values folders.

- values
- values-sw320dp (... to 4'')
- values-sw480dp (5'' to 5,5'')
- values-sw600dp (7'' to 10'')
- values-sw720dp (10'' to ...)

In each folder have one dimens.xml file with different margins, paddings, etc...

But don´t know what specific values folder need to work with display between 4'' and 5'', specifically 4,65'' and 4,7''.

Comment: you have to keep experimenting.. :( .. there are folders like values-hdpi, and also values-xhdpi.. may be you should put your resources in either one of them and then check alternatively as to which folder is used when dealing with 4.7 and 4.65" devices

Answer (score 5):

Check the correct device resolution and follow the charts offered by Android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**Configuration examples:**

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
  hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

*in your case you will have your 4,65'' device in "values-480dp" folder.*

Comment: If i want to design for landscape then what is the sequence of the name values folder?